# Why did Branagh's "Hamlet" have such a limited release in theaters?

Tags: hamlet

I read on the wikipedia page for Kenneth Branagh's 4-hour epic version of [*Hamlet* (1996)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamlet_(1996_film)) that it was only released on fewer than 100 screens in the US and was ultimately not a success at the box office due to such a limited release.

So, why was its box office release so limited? It was a pretty major production, surely they expected to earn their money back on it somehow?

Comment: `4-hour epic version` is your answer. A limited number of people will sit for a movie that long, and a limited number of theaters will add space for a movie that they will only be able to show twice a day.

Comment: *I am writing to you regarding the film “Hamlet” in 70mm. We saw a lot of advertising both on the television and movie magazines saying how good it was and that it was in 70mm. So naturally we were really looking forward to it. So imagine our disappointment when we found it was only opening at one cinema in greater Manchester (in 35mm, editor). That was at the Odeon and they have not got a 70mm screen. I rang our local multiplex “Warner Brothers” and got the excuse they couldn’t cope with the intermission. They hadn’t the facilities.* https://www.in70mm.com/newsletter/1997/48/hamlet/index.htm

Answer (score -1):

There were various reasons for the limited release. The four hour, two minute runtime was the obvious one, but the other reason was that Branagh shot the entire film on 70mm film, and that also limited what theatres could show it. Not that I'm complaining, that movie looked magnificent in 70. Back then people were not fond of being in theatres for that long (pre Avatar and LOTR) so theatres were hesitant to screen it.